# Preview and Skim are not opening Latex compiled pdf file

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, latex

I am using `latexmk` to compile file written in `Latex` in OS X (macOS Sierra : 10.12.4) to `pdf`.

Recently I am facing that such pdf files are not being opened through `Preview` or `Skim` pdf editor! Earlier I didn't have such an issue.

Any fix?

Answer (score 1):

My machine has MacOS 10.12.5 and MacTeX-2016 and it works fine, both with Preview and Skim. I used the command-line in Terminal. Here are what `latexmk --version` and `pdflatex --version` report on my system, respectively.

```
Latexmk, John Collins, 22 April 2016. Version 4.45

pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.21; using libpng 1.6.21
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

I know this does not really qualify as an answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question!

Comment: @LucJBourhis I have upgraded to MacOS 10.12.5, and reinstalled MacTeX-2016 and Skim. Still no luck. :(

Comment: Sorry, I missed your answer. Do you get any error message? If you do `open your.pdf` in Terminal, do you get any info? For the record, my version of Skim is  1.4.29 (103). Also could you copy me the output of a fresh latexmk run?

Comment: @LucBourhis Sorry, what output do you want? The printout on the screen (but there's no error in Latex)?  My Skim version is the same as yours.

Comment: I was wondering whether `open your.pdf` in Terminal would print some warning or error.

Comment: @LucJBourhis No error message on the terminal. I can send you the crash report if you want through conversation.